# Xcode 13 Unable to get wifi networks : "nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request"

Tags: swift, xcode, wifi, nehotspothelper

I want to get all nearby networks(and/or the network the device is connected to).
I am using Xcode 13 IOS14 and this code:

```
NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent(completionHandler: { (network) in  
    if let unwrappedNetwork = network {  
        let networkSSID = unwrappedNetwork.ssid  
        print("Network: %{public}@ ", networkSSID )  
    } else {   
        print("No available network")               
    }           
})
```

info.plist:

[image]

Capabilities:

[image]

I tried this code and got this line:
`NEHotspotNetwork` nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request
No available network